# UserControl template is not displaying the Children of a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am creating an application that builds diagrams. The diagrams consist of UserControls added to a Canvas. I would like to print a collection of these diagrams using a formated UserControl created in xaml.

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
FixedPage page = new FixedPage();

document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth,pd.PrintableAreHeight);
page.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page.Height= document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

PageTemplate template = new PageTemplate();
template.canvas = BuildCanvasFunction();

FixedPage.SetTop(template,0);
FixedPage.SetLeft(template,0);
page.Children.Add(template);

PageContent content = new PageContent();
content.Child = page;
document.Pages.Add(content);
pd.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Document");
```

Template.Xaml template

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinition>

   <TextBlock Text="Test" Grid.Row="0"/>
   <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Name="canvas"/>
<Grid>
```

The issue I'm having is that though the canvas is displayed none of its children are. The template just displays a blank canvas. I have checked with the debugger to confirm that the canvas has all of its children they just aren't being displayed.

The TextBlock within the template is being displayed correctly. The xaml.cs for the template is currently empty as I am not doing anything with the template, I'm just using it to organize preexisting controls.

The Diagram is usually displayed in the UI in the order: TabControl>TabItem>ScrollViewer>Canvas. This configuration displays the diagram correctly. When the diagram is added to the template however the children fail to display.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "printed" what driver are you using?  The Print To PDF Driver?  Because I've had all sorts of problems with that.  I had documents that printed out fine on a physical printer but empty on the MS Print-to-PDF driver.

But if I used a third-party Print-To-PDF driver, they looked great.

Comment: Yes it happen when i use the print to pdf driver. Though to confirm it wasn't just the driver I have attempted to display the fixedpage within the application, and the behavior persists. It will display the canvas, but not its children.

Comment: Well before you can worry about printing your XAML pages, you need worry about showing them correctly in the UI.  If that's not working for you then the issue is in your XAML, not in the printing code.

Comment: I agree, I can display the diagram fine if I add it into a Scrollviewer, which is how it's viewed within the UI . The issue is only relevant when I attempt to add the canvas to a FixedPage in order to print.

Comment: I think your next step would be to edit your question to show us how you are building the document then, not how you are trying to print it.  When I do this, I declare the `DocumentViewer` in XAML.  I set its alignment values to ensure it's filling the screen.   Then, in code-behind, in the `Loaded` event handler, in code-behind, I create my pages and add them to the children.  Without seeing how you do things, nobody here can help you

Comment: I have just tried to display the template within the UI am just realizing that the template itself doesn't display the children of the canvas. Based on this I don't believe that it is a FixedPage issue as I first believed it to be. Also in regards to how I am building the document other than setting the page width and height what I have posed above is all that I have atm. I was ensuring that the Diagram would display correctly before I begun to format the document. My PageTemplate class is a UserControl, I'm not sure if that contributes to the issue with the canvas children not showing up.